# Ajax login with server-side validation using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm writing an ASP.NET application that requires users to log on to a server using an external API. I would like users to be given instant feedback, using Ajax, if they input invalid login credentials.

My view

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Login", null, new { id = "login-form" }))
        { 
            <label>
                User Name: @Html.TextBox("userName", "", new { @class = "input" })
            </label>
            <label>
                Password: @Html.Password("password", "", new { @class = "input" })
            </label>
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="Login" />
            <div id="login-validate">Invalid Login!</div>
        }
```

My controller

```
    public ActionResult Login(string userName, string password)
    {
        // Returns true if connection is valid
        if (RepoConnection.verifyAndBindConn(userName, password))
        {
            return Index(); // Redirect to home page, logged in as new user
        }
        else
        {
            return null; // TODO: Don't change view
        }
    }
```

Is there a way to have the controller not switch the view, and instead call a jQuery function to display the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return `View()` in your else block. It will redisplay the login page.

```
    if (RepoConnection.verifyAndBindConn(userName, password))
    {
        return Index(); // Redirect to home page, logged in as new user
    }
    else
    {
        return View(); // TODO: Don't change view
    }
```

If you really want it to be ajaxy, you are going to have to change your code to not use a form/submit button but to send your login credentials via ajax, write the session cookie, and handle the redirect in js code.

Comment: The login page is actually a dropdown on a master page, so this wouldn't work the best. I guess I'll need to look into the other options.